# oracle docker port conflict

Tags: oracle, dockerfile, listener

Need your assistance please.

created two containers on 19.3e but there is conflict when i open both the same time...

```
docker run -d --name oracle1931 -p 1522:1521 -e ORACLE_PWD=password123 -v oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata test/oracledb:latest
docker run -d --name oracle1931 -p 1522:1521 -e ORACLE_PWD=password123 -v oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata test/oracledb:latest

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                            PORTS                    NAMES
47b792580c29   test/oracledb:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'exec $O…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:1523->1523/tcp   oracle193
88d4d0b326ae   test/oracledb:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'exec $O…"   3 hours ago     Up About an hour (healthy)        0.0.0.0:1522->1521/tcp   oracle1931
```

My second container fails to work with the below even though it is redirected to host port as 1522. Thoughts?

```
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "ORCLCDB" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "ORCLCDB", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly the second container that shows the issue is named "oracle193" (I assume that based on the container health check status and age) and if all that is true that's because the container is bound to 1523 on the host and is listening to port 1523 also inside the container which is the wrong port, oracle uses port 1521 (that's why the container named "oracle1931" that is showing as up and healthy for 3 hours is probably running correctly)
Again because though the host port is 1522 the container port being listened is 1521.

Reference to oracle port for connecting to the DB under "Oracle Net Listener":

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/rilin/port-numbers-and-protocols-of-oracle-components.html#GUID-D168F70C-BECE-4F9A-B616-D9103A35F1FF

Helps this resolves the issue, and remember when bringing up a container and bounding to port with docker the first port is on the host and the second after the colons is the one being listened from inside the container.

Reference from docker official documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Cheers